# Python: catch git error

Tags: python, git, github

I'm trying to catch a very simple error, but with no result for now.

I've created a tag on my Git repository and trying to catch an error with the creation of existing tag. My code looks like:

```
try:
    check_call(['git', 'tag', '-a', '1.2.3', '-m', 'test tag.'])
except CalledProcessError as err:
    print err.output, err.returncode, err.message
```

I can't catch a message: `tag '1.2.3' already exists`.
It raises in my git command, but I can't catch it.

I was also trying to replace `check_call` with `check_output`, but it also doesn't help.

Using just a `returncode` is not enough for me, because it raises `128` for this case and many others (I want to have separate handling for different issues).

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `check_output()` to get the output. The reason you do not get that working, is because the error message is not written to `stdout` but to `stderr`. This can easily be taken care of by redirecting `stderr`to `stdout`. Using the following should work for you:

```
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError
try:
    check_output(['git', 'tag', '-a', '1.2.3', '-m', 'test tag.'], stderr=STDOUT)
except CalledProcessError as err:
    print err.output, err.returncode, err.message
```

Here you can see that I have used `check_output()` and redirected `stderr` .

Comment: It looks good. I was also trying something similar, but I was trying to store this output into the variable.... It looks like that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the answer.

```
import subprocess

command = ['git', 'tag', '-a', '1.2.3', '-m', 'test tag.']

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

output = p.stdout.read()

p.communicate()

if p.returncode == 0:
    handleSuccess() # supposed you have such a function
else:
    # you can handle any error based on the output of git
    if 'tag' in output and 'already exists' in output:
        handleTagAlreadyExistsError() # supposed you have such a function
```

Comment: ```>>> try:
...     check_call(['git', 'tag', '-a', '1.2.3', '-m', 'test tag.'])
... except CalledProcessError as err:
...     print "Message: %s" % err.message
... 
fatal: tag '1.2.3' already exists
Message:``` I was trying something similar, but `err.message` is empty!

Comment: I rewrote my answer to address your issue correctly. Hope, it helps. Please let me know if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I want to avoid `Popen`, `communicate`, etc. as it may be not clear enough from the first point.

Comment: What's the reason to avoid Popen or communicate() ?

Comment: It's not clear from the first point of view what is going on. Just try to compare: `check_call(['git', 'checkout', 'master'])` and `p = Popen('git checkout master', stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT); out = p.stdout.read();p.communicate()`

Comment: documentation of check_call says avoid using stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE as they may cause deadlocks. Also, it suggests to use Popen.communicate to read stdout and/or stderr.